# find parameter a so that X+Y and X+aY are uncorrelated

Tags: correlation, random-variable

Given random variable X and Y such that E(X)=0, E(Y)=-1 Var(X)=1, Var(Y)=4 Var(X+Y)=9. Find parameter a  so that X+Y and X+aY are uncorrelated. The answer is -1/2. Would appreciate any tips on how to approach this.

I found these pages but not sure how to use the info. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncorrelatedness_(probability_theory)#Definition_for_two_real_random_variables

[In practice, how to clearly prove that variables are uncorrelated?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210670/in-practice-how-to-clearly-prove-that-variables-are-uncorrelated)

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to find $a$ such that $\text{Cov}(X+Y,X+aY)=0$. We can start by expanding that expression, using some [properties of covariances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Covariance_of_linear_combinations):

$$\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(X+Y,X+aY)&=\text{Cov}(X+Y,X)+\text{Cov}(X+Y,aY)\\
&=\text{Cov}(X,X)+\text{Cov}(X,Y)+\text{Cov}(X,aY)+\text{Cov}(Y,aY)\\
&=\text{Cov}(X,X)+\text{Cov}(X,Y)+a\cdot\text{Cov}(X,Y)+a\cdot\text{Cov}(Y,Y)\\
&=\text{Var}(X)+(a+1)\cdot\text{Cov}(X,Y)+a\cdot\text{Var}(Y)
\end{align}$$
Now, we have to find $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$. Since $\text{Var}(X+Y)=9$, we have:
$$\begin{align}
\text{Var}(X+Y)&=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)+2\cdot\text{Cov}(X,Y)\\
9&=1+4+2\cdot\text{Cov}(X,Y)
\end{align}$$
Therefore, $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=2$. Now, we can replace this in the previous equation:
$$\text{Cov}(X+Y,X+aY)=1+(a+1)\cdot2+a\cdot4=6a+3$$
Equating that to zero and solving for $a$, we get $a=-\dfrac{1}{2}$, as expected.

Comment: Nice, clear answer.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now! Thanks for pointing me in the direction of properties of covariance. Afterwards, I found these 2 pages to be further helpful.
The comment here from Macro: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721/covariance-of-a-variable-and-a-linear-combination-of-other-variables

And this page from Hunter and Doug: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2947788/what-is-varx-y